# Is there any way to calculate time consumption on androidx.startup?

Tags: android, testing

I recently brought `androidx.startup` library to my project. but I don't know how to calculate time consumption on `androidx.startup` initializing.
Can I get the time consumption on `androidx.startup` initializing by log or some other test framework?

Comment: Why use that library over just using an injection framework, which would be more flexible and far more widely used?  A library like Dagger would do everything that does, provide a much greater set of functionality, and have far less boilerplate

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, androidx.startup focuses on initialization, Dagger focuses on DI. it is not the same thing.

Comment: Sure it is.  You initialize everything via injection.  That's what pretty much every app does these days.  All this does is create a bunch of objects and subobject.  That's what DI does.  The onCreate is the equivalent of Dagger's @Provides method, and the dependencies function is the equivalent to the list of parameters to it.

Comment: ALthough the trivial answer to your question-  take the topmost item in your dependency graph.  Instrument the onCreate function for that item so it logs the time.  That's how long it takes, plus a few milliseconds.  If you have multiple top level items, instrument all of them, or create a top level item to encapsulate them all.